# Can't install a specific pypi package JFrog artifactory while already exists in remote cache repostitory

Tags: artifactory, pypi

I want to install a specific pypi package (`cryptography` package) from this command:

```
pip install -i http://JFROG_URL/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/simple --trusted-host JFROG_URL cryptography
```

but i get this errors:

```
ERROR: HTTP error 403 while getting http://JFROG_URL/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/packages/packages/25/1d/f86ce362aedc580c3f90c0d74fa097289e3af9ba52b8d5a37369c186b0f1/cryptography-41.0.4-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#sha256=e40211b4923ba5a6dc9769eab704bdb3fbb58d56c5b336d30996c24fcf12aadb (from http://JFROG_URL/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/simple/cryptography/) (requires-python:>=3.7)

ERROR: Could not install requirement cryptography from http://JFROG_URL/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/packages/packages/25/1d/f86ce362aedc580c3f90c0d74fa097289e3af9ba52b8d5a37369c186b0f1/cryptography-41.0.4-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#sha256=e40211b4923ba5a6dc9769eab704bdb3fbb58d56c5b336d30996c24fcf12aadb because of error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://JFROG_URL/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/packages/packages/25/1d/f86ce362aedc580c3f90c0d74fa097289e3af9ba52b8d5a37369c186b0f1/cryptography-41.0.4-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

while this package already exists in our cache remote repository. For example, I can download this WHL file and install this package manually but I want to install this package from jfrog.

Someone have a idea about this problem.

Comment: Did you try to provide the credentials in the URL?
pip install -i http://<user>:<password>@JFROG_URL/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/simple --trusted-host JFROG_URL cryptography

Comment: Yes I tried this URL and this repos is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I use the `Zap Caches` options in the virtual repository and restart my JFrog artifactory service, it gets the package.